# Get typename of derived class from base instance in C++

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, polymorphism

I am creating a generic error handler for a C++ project. As part of the logging, I want to include the name of the exception class. I'm hoping there's a way to generically get the name of the specific error class from a std::exception instance without having to use dynamic_cast and a logic tree.

Example:

**exception_handler.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <exception>
#include <string>

class ExceptionHandler
{
public:
    static std::string get_exception_type_name(std::exception ex)
    {
        return ((std::string)typeid(ex).name()).substr(11);
    }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "exception_handler.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string any = "any";
    std::out_of_range ex("Out of range exception");

    std::cout << ExceptionHandler::get_exception_type_name(ex) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press any key to close this window..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> any; 
}
```

Executing outputs "exception". I want it to say "out_of_range" or whatever other kind of derived exception I feed into the function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is being [sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). Pass by `const&` instead of by value:

```
static std::string get_exception_type_name(std::exception const& ex)
{                                                       //^^^^^^
    return typeid(ex).name();
}
```

See http://ideone.com/LWoxgm for example.

Comment: Slicing definitely sounds like the culprit, but adding const& to the argument profile did not change the execution output. It's still "exception". Think this might be a compiler issue?

Comment: @kseier: It works fine for me here, after adding necessary headers and removing the substr(11). The string returned by name() is implementation defined, so maybe the part you cut off differs?

Comment: @kseier, try as posted in the answer (without the `substr()`). This should work. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @hmjd: I just got it working for me as well. I had some additional issues in how the exception object was being passed around before it got to this method. Your solution works great. Thanks!

Comment: Part of the trick is to make sure I pass the exception object by reference all the way down the chain to the get_exception_type_name method, which means in my code I need to have `catch (std::exception &ex)` instead of `catch (std::exception ex)`.